# SAML2 Multiple Service Providers

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

We have single sign on implemented in our web product(app1) using SAML 2.0 - our product is the service provider. Now one of our clients is asking for a link in app1 which will take the user to their web app(app2) and they are expecting the user to single sign on into their application. I am assuming that their app(app2) will be using the same IDP as app1 is using.

Based on my understanding I think a link to their AssertionConsumer of app2 should do the work. When the link to the app2 is clicked app2's AssertionConsumer will be able to process the claims from app1. Will appreciate if someone will chime in and let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not link to the Assertion consumer URL. You link to the relevant page in app2. App2 will detect that the user is not authenticated and send it to IDP for authentication. The IDP will detect that the user is already authenticated and return the user to the page it was originally sent to.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry I am not all that familiar with SAML but when I meant Assertion consumer URL I meant AssertionConsumerService location. But I see what you are saying - we need to link to the relevant URL in app2 which communicates with the IDP.

Comment: That is correct. SAML is hard and can be hard at first. Feel free to ask more questions. Please mark the answer as correct

Comment: Hi @StefanRasmusson what app1 sends an API request to app2, how does app2 authenticate against IDP without redirecting the user to IDP?

Answer (score 0):

Does app2 do passive auth when users arrive? If so, you should just link to any page in app2 and let it take care of asking the IdP about the user's login status, rather than trying to tell it.

If app2 doesn't automatically check with the IdP, then you should probably link to a page in app2 that *requires* auth, so that it will.

In general, the whole point of the IdP is that *it's* the thing that the SPs trust to tell them whether (and how) a user is authenticated, so you shouldn't try to build an additional system of trust *between* the SPs. (It's fine if they *hint* to each other that the current user is logged in or even someone in particular, but they should *check with the IdP* before believing it.)

Comment: I still don't have all the info about this app2. Sorry I am not so familiar with SAML but when you say passive auth are you referring to SP initiated authentication.